# Can't compile with Makefile from different source files in different directories

Tags: c++, makefile

I've got a C++ project with this directory structure:

```
src
├── database
│   ├── database.hpp
│   ├── leveldb.cpp
│   └── leveldb.hpp
├── Makefile
└── server.cpp
```

server.cpp includes "database/database.hpp" and "database/leveldb.hpp".
leveldb.cpp includes "leveldb.hpp"

my Makefile is this so far (keep in mind that $LEVELDB is the path to the Google's leveldb libraries and is different from my leveldb.hpp and cpp files, which represent a custom made class):

```
CC=g++
LEVELDB=/route/to/Googles/library/leveldb
BOOST=/route/to/boost/cpp-netlib-0.9.2

DATABASE=/route/to/my/project/src/database

CFLAGS=-I$(LEVELDB)/include -I$(BOOST) -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS=-L$(LEVELDB) -lleveldb -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread

all:server

server: server.cpp database/leveldb.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I$(DATABASE) $< $(LDFLAGS) -L$(DATABASE)
```

I can't get it to compile. It gives me an error "undefined reference to `LevelDB::LevelDB(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'" which I know is a compilation error because of the Makefile, because everything worked fine when I had it all in one single source file.

I'd appreciate so much your help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't `servidor` depend on some object files like `server.o` instead of the cpp file? Try to replace .cpp with .o, and make will generate the object files for you.

Comment: Are you building something in the database directory? because you have `-L$(DATABASE)`

Comment: Make prints out the exact command-line calls to everything it runs, so you should see how it's calling GCC (and you should post it in your question!).  If that doesn't match how you expect GCC to be called, then fix your Makefile until it does.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us whether you are trying to `make` (or `make all` or `make server`) or `make servidor`. Either way, the problem is that you are not linking the `leveldb` definitions into your target.

In this rule:

```
servidor: server.cpp database/leveldb.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -I$(DATABASE) $< $(LDFLAGS) -L$(DATABASE)
```

You are using the automatic variable `$<`, which means the *first* prerequisite, (`server.cpp`). You should use `$^`, which means *all* prerequisites (`server.cpp database/leveldb.cpp`).

If you `make` or `make all` or `make server`, Make will attempt to build `server` from `server.cpp` using default rules which make no mention of `leveldb.cpp`. Are you sure you don't want the rule to be "all:servidor"?

Comment: +1 All that is missing is a [link to reference material](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: sorry, I had an error. "Servidor" is "server". I already corrected it. I want to build server.cpp.